# Matching walking from video to tracked scene?

Tags: animation, effects, motion-capture

I am doing a cgi background in blender to someone walking on a treadmill... I am trying to move the cgi background to match the guys walk. How would I go about this? I already tracked the scene but do I move the background or move the camera to match the walking? I am pretty new to blender and just need some advice :)

Comment: Please post an image of the shot. You don't really need to track the video. It could be a very easy thing to do, or a total nightmare. Please add detailed information on what kind of shot you are dealing with, and if describe the kind of motion within the shot.